# Passing NSManagedObject back in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, delegates, segue

I've tried following this post re: passing data back to a prior viewController without much luck. I've spent more time than I care to admit on this, I've read all I can, yet nothing I've found here works.

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

`Legend:  AddPOIViewController -----------> CategoryViewController`

`Step 1:  empty textField      ---segue---> selectCategory`

`Step 2:  setCategory on CategoryViewController`

`Step 3:  AddPOIViewController <--delegate-- setCategory`

I have an `AddPOIViewController` (A) and a `CategoryViewController` (B). I have a `segue` that works fine from A to B. I want to select a category in B and dump it back in A.

Here's what I've done:

**AddPOIViewController.h**

In my segue from `AddPOIViewController` to `CategoryTableViewController`, I set the delegate as follows:

```
 CategoryTableViewController *categoryTableViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
 categoryTableViewController.delegate = (id<CategoryTableViewControllerDelegate>)self;


// Delegate method
 - (void)addItemViewController:(CategoryTableViewController *)controller didSelectCategory:(LocationCategory *)selectedCategory {
    NSLog(@"This was returned from CategoryTVC: %@", self.selectedCategory);
}
```

**CategoryTableViewController.h**

```
// This property sets CategoryTVC as the delgate of AddPOIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CategoryTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

// This property is public so the AddPOIVC knows about it
@property (nonatomic, strong) LocationCategory *selectedCategory;
```

**CategoryTableViewController.h**

```
    - (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
        [self.delegate categoryTableViewControllerDidSave:self];    
    // This passes the value back to the AddPOIViewController
    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didSelectCategory:self.selectedCategory];
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Are there any error logs?

Comment: I'm returning `(null)` for `addItemViewController`

Comment: There are no errors, it doesn't crash. I just can't get the object to pass back to `VC1` from the `VC2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the IBAction `done:` method in `CategoryTableViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate categoryTableViewControllerDidSave:self];    
    // This passes the value back to the AddPOIViewController
    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didSelectCategory:self.selectedCategory];
}
```

The problem is that the first line of this method calls the delegate's `categoryTableViewControllerDidSave:` method, which dismisses the view controller:

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

So the `CategoryTableViewController` gets dismissed before it can get to the next line, where is passes the NSManagedObject.

To fix it, just switch round the two lines in the IBAction `done:` method:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    // This passes the value back to the AddPOIViewController
    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didSelectCategory:self.selectedCategory];
    // This causes this view controller to be dismissed:
    [self.delegate categoryTableViewControllerDidSave:self];    
}
```

You also need to save the `selectedCategory` that is passed in the call to the `selectedCategory` property of `AddPOIViewController`:

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(CategoryTableViewController *)controller didSelectCategory:(LocationCategory *)selectedCategory {
    self.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    NSLog(@"This was returned from CategoryTVC: %@", self.selectedCategory);
}
```

Comment: Still `null`. I was working on it with my mentor & there was a value displayed for it when I hovered over it at the breakpoint we set, but I never looked at the log statement to see what it was printing from the `NSLog` I threw in there, though I did print it when I was hovering over it.

Comment: Amended my answer - you need to save the value passed in the method call to the `self.selectedCategory` property.

Comment: Oh man! I'm going to take my beating like a man and leave this up unedited ;) Thank you for getting me squared away on this.

Comment: No problem - we all find we can't see the wood for the trees sometimes.